# In-Place upgrade from SQL Sever 2014 to 2017 finds nothing to upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, upgrade

I'm attempting an in place upgrade from SQL 2014 to SQL 2017, Standard Edition on Windows 2012 R2 (Yes, I know...)  The issue is that the installer never presents me with a screen to select the instance and under Select Features, there are no options, just greyed out entries for Shared Features and Redistributable Features (no checkboxes).  Because I already upgraded SQL Browser/Writer, hitting Next> at this point gives me the validation errors dialog and the installer shows "There are no features selected for upgrade".  I've run the system configuration check report and migration assistant - all green.  The summary.txt file shows that it discovered Database Engine Services, Reporting Services - Native, SSMS, and Adv_SSMS, all SQL 2014.

The installer is fine.  If I begin to install a named instance of 2017, it provides me with features to select.  I did the same with a 2016 installer and had the same problem.

At this point, I'm at a loss for what to do next except uninstall 2014 and install 2017, which is a pain.  Note that we were successful uninstalling SSRS 2014 and installing 2017 though we rolled that change back with a snapshot when we hit the engine upgrade roadblock.

Grateful for any troubleshooting thoughts.

Comment: At the first sign of trouble with an in-place upgrade you should _strongly_ consider doing a side-by-side upgrade, and especially here where your Windows Server is so old.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft:  The idea behind the in place upgrade is actually that it's a stepping stone to also doing an in place upgrade on the OS.  Again, not my idea.  My gut says we'll end up moving the DBs to a different 2017 instance and leave this server to the SCCM components that are driving this effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to answer my own question.

The solution in this case was to do a command prompt upgrade.  The command was as simple as this:

setup.exe /Q /ACTION=UPGRADE /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER

In my case, because there was still an SSRS 2014 instance on the server, we had to go through the whole uninstall of SSRS 2014/install of SSRS 2017 process first (which was in our plans anyway), as the upgrade identifies this instance with the following error:

Message:
The /IAcceptRSUninstall command line parameter is missing or has not been set to true. It is a required parameter for the setup action you are running. By specifying this parameter, you acknowledge that Reporting Services will be uninstalled and you have performed any necessary backup and/or migration.

I really believed that the command prompt upgrade would fail and was just hoping for a better error message in the logs, which is why we didn't bother to do the SSRS step first.  But, once we completed that, the 2017 upgrade ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your SQL 2014 is 32-bit? SQL 2017 is only available as 64-bit:

SQL Server 2017 (14.x) is only available for 64-bit platforms. Cross-platform upgrade is not supported. You cannot upgrade a 32-bit instance of SQL Server to native 64-bit using SQL Server Setup. However, you can back up or detach databases from a 32-bit instance of SQL Server, and then restore or attach them to a new instance of SQL Server (64-bit) if the databases are not published in replication. You must re-create any logins and other user objects in master, msdb, and model system databases.

Comment: Nope:  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505217) - 12.0.5223.6 (X64).  There was previously a 32 bit SQL Express install on this server as well, which I thought might be confusing the installer but I've finally been able to uninstall it (it was unused) and that did not solve my problem.